# How to let a docker container interact with a native program?

Tags: docker

If you have two programs that want to communicate and one of them is a docker container how would this be done?

Ex in Windows there is shared memory

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: The easiest method is for the host process to make something like an HTTP call to a container process.  This will also work with appropriate configuration in cluster environments like Kubernetes, or if you're not using a container system at all but the two components are running on separate machines.

Answer (score 2):

I see two options to comunicate between a local process and another process running inside a docker container

1. Exposing a container's port
2. Using sockets

**Using container's port**

Expose a internal's container port using `-p|--publish` flag:

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 nginx
```

This way you can use `tcp` or `udp` protocols to interact with your process running inside the container using the client-server model

+info

- Publish ports - https://docs.docker.com/network/#published-ports
- Dockerfile `EXPOSE` - https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose

**Using sockets**

Mount a socket file as a volume on your container using `-v|--volume` flag:

```
docker run -d -v /path/to/file.sock:/path/to/file.sock example
```

This way you can interact with the local socket file which is going to be bind inside the container, so both processes (local and inside the container) will be able to communicate

Comment: `EXPOSE` being the key word here in the `Dockerfile`.

Comment: @tadman EXPOSE is only documentation, so it doesn't matter if you include it or not. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose paragraph 2.

Comment: @HansKilian Not necessarily. Depending on how you launch it, anything set with `EXPOSE` can get mapped automatically.